# problem with 3d parametric plots and view from top

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

Im plotting parametric functions and getting different views of them. The problem is the top view, specifically when the function varies in the z direction,  the perspective is not correct. Code examples and image

```
\documentclass[varwidth ,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,tikz-3dplot}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
%\pgfplotsset{,compat=1.17}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
%   
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
        view={-45}{45},
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        zlabel=$z$,
        ]
        \addplot3 [surf] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
    view={0}{90},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    ]
    \addplot3 [surf] {x+y};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[view={60}{30}]
        \addplot3[
        domain=0:5*pi,
        samples=201,
        samples y=1, ](
        {sin(deg(x))},
        {cos(deg(x))},
        {2*x/(5*pi)}
        );
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
        \addplot3[
        domain=0:5*pi,
        samples=201,
        samples y=1, ](
        {sin(deg(x))},
        {cos(deg(x))},
        {2*x/(5*pi)}
        );
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture} [trig format=rad ]
    \begin{axis}[view={60}{-40}]]
        \addplot3 [surf, variable=t,
        domain=0:5*pi,
        samples=501,
        samples y=1](
        {0.5*t*cos(10*t)},
        {0.5*t*sin(10*t)},
        {pi-1*t}
        );
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture} [trig format=rad ]
    \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
        \addplot3 [surf, variable=t,
        domain=0:5*pi,
        samples=501,
        samples y=1](
        {0.5*t*cos(10*t)},
        {0.5*t*sin(10*t)},
        {pi-0.5*t}
        );
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image: 3d view vs top view]
the last one view is not correct
Any suggestions?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you use `trig format=rad`. `pgfplots` uses trigonometric functions to install the view, and you "screw them up" (this is not meant to be offensive). This is why `pgfplots` has an option `trig format plots=rad`. The other effects are partly because you change the function, e.g. `{x}` goes to `{x+y}`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth ,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,tikz-3dplot}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
%   
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
        view={-45}{45},
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        zlabel=$z$,
        ]
        \addplot3 [surf] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
    view={0}{90},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    ]
    \addplot3 [surf] {x+y};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[view={60}{30}]
        \addplot3[
        domain=0:5*pi,
        samples=201,
        samples y=1, ](
        {sin(deg(x))},
        {cos(deg(x))},
        {2*x/(5*pi)}
        );
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
        \addplot3[
        domain=0:5*pi,
        samples=201,
        samples y=1, ](
        {sin(deg(x))},
        {cos(deg(x))},
        {2*x/(5*pi)}
        );
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}% [trig format=rad ]
    \begin{axis}[view={60}{-40},trig format plots=rad]
        \addplot3 [surf, variable=t,
        domain=0:5*pi,
        samples=501,
        samples y=1](
        {0.5*t*cos(10*t)},
        {0.5*t*sin(10*t)},
        {pi-1*t}
        );
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}%[trig format=rad]
    \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},trig format plots=rad]
        \addplot3 [mesh, variable=t,
        domain=0:5*pi,
        samples=501,
        samples y=0, 
        mesh/ordering=y varies,
        %z buffer=sort
        ](
        {0.5*t*cos(10*t)},
        {0.5*t*sin(10*t)},
        {pi-0.5*t}
        );
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]